# Why am I getting Forbidden 403 while trying to authenticate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-jdbc

I am trying to authenticate user but I am getting forbidden response.

**CustomUserDetailService.java**

public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

```
private String id;
private String username;
private String password;
private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
    this.id = user.getId();
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRole().split(","))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

}

**UserDetailService.java**

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final AuthenticationDao authenticationDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(authenticationDao.getUserByUsername(username));

        if(user.isPresent()) {
            CustomUserDetails customUserDetails =  new CustomUserDetails(user.get());
            return customUserDetails;
        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(Util.CANNOT_FIND_USER_BY_USERNAME);
        }
    }
}
```

**Querying user using username**

```
 @Override
    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?",
                    new Object[]{username}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(User.class));
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException exception) {
            log.error("Cannot find user by username: {}", username);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.treeleaf.auth.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@Log4j2
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Security Filter chain....");
        http.cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(configurationSource()));
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Content-Disposition");
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
}
```

**Authentication in Service**

```
    @Override
    public AuthResponse authenticate(AuthRequest authRequest) {
        System.out.println(authRequest.toString());
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
        );
        String token = generateToken(authentication);
        return new AuthResponse(token);
    }
```

I am trying to authenticate user. There is no problems with request it's hitting service layer but the problem arises when trying to do authentication.authenticate(username, password). Anyone please help me with this !

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue. The issue was with CustomUserDetailService.java where I have returned false for isNonExpired, isNonLocked, isEnabled.